Lambda Handler not found from bucket
So i got a lambda that is deployed from cdk.
The code is fromBucket and the object name is users.zip
The users.zip has an index.js which exports the handler as follows
// removed for brevity
(() => {
var exports = __webpack_exports__;

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", ({ value: true }));
exports.handler = void 0;
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: result }),
    };
};

exports.handler = handler;

})();

basically exports.handler = handler;
I verified that the index.js is in the root of the users.zip
But i keep getting the error
Error: Cannot find module 'index'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs"

I also uploaded the file manually to make sure nothing happens during the deployment but that did not work either
Any ideas?

It seems the issue is with the **Lambda handler **, check your Lambda handler with the correct function path. If your index.js is in the root folder, then the handler value should be index.handler_function

Cheers @Aravindanvaithialingam i verified that still can not find the index. I also tried changing the name of the entry file from index to main but nothing yet

So it turns out the issue was i forgot the --tsc flag during the build process. :facepalm:
